# Conditional frequencies calculation for more than one variable

Tags: r, statistics

I want to calculate conditional probabilities in my data. Therefore I coded the following:

```
creditrisks <- read.table("kredit.asc", header=TRUE)
glimpse(creditrisks)

creditrisks$moral1 <- as.integer(moral>1)
creditrisks$konto1 <- as.integer(laufkont==1)
creditrisks$konto2 <- as.integer(laufkont==4)
creditrisks$zweck <- as.integer(0<verw & verw<9)

attach(creditrisks)

prop.table(table(kredit,konto1),2)
prop.table(table(kredit,konto2),2)
prop.table(table(kredit,moral1),2)
prop.table(table(kredit,zweck),2)
```

The results look like this:

[image: Table 1]

This works well for me, the only thing I want to change is that I can calculate all conditional frequencies at once, so the table should look like this:

[image: Table 2]

With cbind I loose all the variable names, so I'm searching for a more elegant way.

The dataset can be found here: [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9rvtpl1sa7xa7b/kredit.asc?dl=0)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
lapply(creditrisks[, c("konto1", "konto2", "moral1", "zweck")],
       function(x) prop.table(table(creditrisks$kredit, x), 2)
       )
```

You can also `cbind` them together by

```
do.call(cbind, 
        lapply(
          creditrisks[, c("konto1", "konto2", "moral1", "zweck")],
          function(x) prop.table(table(creditrisks$kredit, x), 2)
          )
        )
```